# NPi i.MX6ULL Linux SBC - Difficulty Finding Linux Headers

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I am currently using a NPi i.MX6ULL Dev Board Linux SBC.

I am trying to get SPI functionality up and running by following the tutorials that are on: https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/NPi-i.MX6ULL-Dev-Board-Linux-SBC/#spi

One of the commands that you run in this tutorial is:
apt install -y make git device-tree-compiler linux-headers-$(uname -r) gcc

When I run this command, I am unable to obstain any packages for my linux version.

Command Result:

> Reading package lists… Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information… Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.71-imx-r1
>
> E: Couldn’t find any package by glob ‘linux-headers-4.19.71-imx-r1’
>
> E: Couldn’t find any package by regex ‘linux-headers-4.19.71-imx-r1’

I'm using the latest firmware that is hosted on SEEED's website. (uname -r: **4.19.71-imx-r1**)

I am at a loss for what I should do here. I am pretty sure that I need these dependencies, because the following steps has me clone a github repo and I am missing things to preform the make operation.

```
root@npi:~# git clone https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/seeed-linux-dtverlays

Cloning into 'seeed-linux-dtverlays'...

remote: Enumerating objects: 385, done.

remote: Counting objects: 100% (385/385), done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (161/161), done.

remote: Total 1341 (delta 253), reused 341 (delta 222), pack-reused 956

Receiving objects: 100% (1341/1341), 1.73 MiB | 1.46 MiB/s, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (592/592), done.

root@npi:~# cd seeed-linux-dtverlays/

root@npi:~/seeed-linux-dtverlays# make all_imx6ull && make install_imx6ull

  DTC     overlays/imx6ull/imx-gpio-grove-button.dtbo

  DTC     overlays/imx6ull/imx-seeed-voicecard-2mic-overlay.dtbo

  DTC     overlays/imx6ull/imx-MCP2517FD-can0-overlay.dtbo

  DTC     overlays/imx6ull/imx-uart3-e-ink.dtbo

  DTC     overlays/imx6ull/imx-i2c2-overlay.dtbo

  DTC     overlays/imx6ull/imx-fire-lcd5-01-overlay.dtbo

make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.19.71-imx-r1/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.

make: *** [Makefile:151: all_imx6ull] Error 2
```

Any help or suggestions that anyone could provide would be EXTRODINARILY helpful. I'm willing to try pretty much anything here.

EDIT:

So I tried to remove the rest of the -imx-r1 tags on the linux version to pick up just the files I think I might need. It doesn’t look like there is a host file yet for the device-tree-compiler for -imx-r1 yet.

```
root@npi:~/seeed-linux-dtoverlays# apt install -y make git device-tree-compiler linux-headers-4.19.71  gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.19.71-bone38' for regex 'linux-headers-4.19.71'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.19.71-armv7-rt-x38' for regex 'linux-headers-4.19.71'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.19.71-armv7-lpae-x38' for regex 'linux-headers-4.19.71'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.19.71-armv7-x38' for regex 'linux-headers-4.19.71'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.19.71-bone-rt-r38' for regex 'linux-headers-4.19.71'
device-tree-compiler is already the newest version (1.4.7-3).
gcc is already the newest version (4:8.3.0-1).
gcc set to manually installed.
git is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3).
make is already the newest version (4.2.1-1.2).
make set to manually installed.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.19.71-armv7-lpae-x38 linux-headers-4.19.71-armv7-rt-x38
  linux-headers-4.19.71-armv7-x38 linux-headers-4.19.71-bone-rt-r38
  linux-headers-4.19.71-bone38
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 372 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

It is still broken however, when I try to run the make command.

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.19.71-imx-r1/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:151: all_imx6ull] Error 2
```

It is specifically looking for the -imx-r1, but I don’t think it exists?

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that I needed some other dependencies like I thought.

I needed to install the files located here:

https://seeed-studio.github.io/seeed-linux-deb/

```
echo "deb https://seeed-studio.github.io/seeed-linux-deb/ buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/seeed.list

curl -k https://seeed-studio.github.io/seeed-linux-deb/public.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

After I did this, I was able to run the other commands that I needed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-headers-4.19.71-imx-r1
```

Oh I also did a "apt full-upgrade" command just in case.